# Washed out textures in Unity

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a problem. After I modelled objects in Blender I textured them and textures are as I need them to be - with saturated colors.

[image]

However, as soon as I export it to the .FBX format and put them on the Unity scene, the textures become pale.

[image: https://yapx.ru/v/D8Wg0]

I suspect this is related to some Blender options but I can't be sure as I'm novice. I searched answer in the internet and didn't find it, how is possible to fix it.

Comment: Hi Slam, welcome to Blender.SE. Unfortunately question here are only supported in English. Please try to edit your question and translate everything into english to your best abilities. Thank you.

Comment: If your textures in <random game engine> don't look the same as they do in Blender, the problem is most possibly on <random game engine>'s side.

Comment: As far as I can see, its just different default lighting.

Answer (score 0):

.fbx files do not transfer textures, so you need to manually apply them in unity. However, the unwrapping should transfer over, so all you need to do is apply the textures manually in Unity.